# Adding a custom button in Jvectormap

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

Is there any way to add a  custom button on the **top left corner** of a normal Jvectormap? *(similar to the back button in a drill-down map)*.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div as a child of the map, so you can position it relative to the map container:

```
$("#map").append('<div id="map-action">Action</div>').click(function () {
  //do your action here
});
```

Style it like you want, important here is to set the z-order, so it lies above the map:

CSS:

```
#map-action {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #292929;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```